# LaTeX minted package not working with `\begin{minted}` anymore on win10?

Tags: python, windows, pygments, xelatex, pygmentize

I've been using minted without any problem for years.
I'm an Windows 10 and MacOS.

Here's a minimal example compiled with xelatex:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{minted}

Hi !

\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{python}
print("hello")
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

This produces only "Hi !" and does not print the python code anymore without returning any error message, whereas `\mintinline` and `\inputmint` work just fine.

I reinstalled Win10 several times, trying on MikTeX and TeXLive, compiling with TeXstudio or TeXworks to no avail (of course using `-shell-escape`).

I tried several versions of `pygments`. I use Python 3.9.9.

Everything works fine on my mac, though.

Does anyone have a clue ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's a bug in fancyvrb, you can find a workaround in this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/623823/36296

Comment: ("Hi" must be after `\begin{document}`)

Comment: Thanks, problem solved, you are my hero :)

Comment: You're welcome!